# Can adjusting color (or grayscale) properties of an image affect its visibility in daylight?

Tags: color, photo-editing, color-theory, visual-artifacts

I'm trying to find ways to make images more visible under daylight (*i.e.,* when daylight reflects off the image screen/print).  For my project, I want to display digital images on an electronic display in daylight, but I am generally curious about techniques/tricks for enhancing visibility in daylight for both digital and print images.

I recently stumbled across the term "daylight grayscale", but am having trouble finding out exactly it means?  Is it a technique that can be accomplished/reproduced using image editing software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best ways of making a display more visible in daylight are physical.

1. Use a non-reflective (matte) screen.
2. Set appropriate brightness to overcome ambient light levels. Or use a monitor that automatically compensates.
3. Install the screen so as to avoid direct light. (Assuming you have control over this, e.g. some a kiosk situation.)
4. Provide a shade to eliminate direct light on the screen.
5. Design the interface with strong contrast, large readable type and icons, ample spacing, appropriate non-dissonant colours, etc. etc.

It's a big subject area. Perhaps provide more information about your particular problem domain.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you print on paper will be visible in daylight. You may want to consider a non-gloss paper, but that's probably not much of an issue anyways.

As for screens, there's no specific technique for your images as you are entirely at the mercy of the display device. How well a screen is visible in sunlight is going to depend on the hardware more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

"daylight greyscale" means, in terms of electronic displays, greyscale mode (i.e. no colors) with no backlight (i.e. relies on ambient lighting).

Obviously, this is a hardware feature of a display, not an image nor file storage technique.